# Partition list based on elements of another list as keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I combine these two lists and use `alist` as keys and `blist` as values? What I would like to do is group the values in `blist` with the corresponding keys. So let's say values `3, 4, 2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` should have `'Inner OD'` as key and the remaining should have a key `'Outter OD'`: `None, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3`

so basically I would want it to look like this

```
{'Inner OD': [3, 4, 2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Outter OD': [None, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3]})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
alist = [u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD',    u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD'] 

blist =  [3, 4, 2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, None, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
res = {}
for i in range(len(alist)):
    if alist[i] in res:
        res[alist[i]].append(blist[i])
    else:
        res[alist[i]]=[blist[i]]
```

returns `{'Inner OD': [2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, None, 3, 4, 6], 'Outter OD': [3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3]}`

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark the answer correct if it is :)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution. It does nothing better than @Tryph's answer (which does nothing better than the @Gábor Erdős's answer) but I think using `defaultdict` makes the logic a bit cleaner:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(alist, blist):
    res[a].append(b)
```

A `defaultdict` behaves almost the same as a dictionary, so you can probably just use the `res` above for the rest of your code; but, if you want, you can turn it into a regular dictionary with

```
res = dict(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing better than the @Gábor Erdős answer but I think it is a bit clearer:

```
>>> alist = [u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD',    u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Inner OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD',u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD', u'Outter OD']
>>> blist =  [3, 4, 2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, None, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3]
>>> res = {}
>>> for key, val in zip(alist, blist):
...     if key in res:
...         res[key].append(val)
...     else:
...         res[key] = [val]
...
>>> res
{u'Inner OD': [2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, None, 3, 4, 6], u'Outter OD': [3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3]}
```

more information about the zip builtin function [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)